# How to make custom dropdownmenu?

Tags: flutter

How to change the width and height of the DropdownMenu without changing the width of the DropdownButton? I need when the DropdownButton is pressed then DropdownMenu fill the entire screen. How to change the position of the DropdownMenu so that it appears below the button, but does not overlap it?

```
 String dropdownValue = '1';
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     theme: new ThemeData(
       brightness: Brightness.light,
       primaryColor: Color...,
       accentColor: Colors...,
     ),
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     home: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         actions: <Widget>[
           Container(
             padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 265.0, 0.0),
             child: CustomDropdownButton<String>(
               value: dropdownValue,
               icon:
                   Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: Colors...),
               iconSize: 21,
               elevation: 16,
               style:
                   TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
               underline: Container(
                 width: 200,
                 height: 2,
                 color: Colors...,
               ),
               onChanged: (String newValue) {
                 setState(() {
                   dropdownValue = newValue;
                 });
               },
               items: <String>[
                 '1',
                 '2',
                 '3',
                 '4'
               ].map<CustomDropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                 return CustomDropdownMenuItem<String>(
                   child: SizedBox(
                     width: 120.0,
                     child: Text("  " + value),
                   ),
                   value: value,
                 );
               }).toList(), ),)...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible to do with `DropdownButton` and `DropdownMenuItem`, but you could achieve this with `PopupMenuButton` and `PopupMenuItem` using the `offset` property.

Here is a quick example of how you could do it:

```
final _itemHeight = 80.0;
final _buttonHeight = 100.0;
final _values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var _selectedValue = 1;

Offset _buildOffset() => Offset(
    0, _buttonHeight * 2 + _values.indexOf(_selectedValue) * _itemHeight * 2);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: PopupMenuButton(
      child: Container(
          color: Colors.yellow,
          height: _buttonHeight,
          width: 100,
          child: Center(child: Text('Item $_selectedValue'))),
      onSelected: (value) => setState(() => _selectedValue = value),
      initialValue: _selectedValue,
      offset: _buildOffset(),
      itemBuilder: (context) => _values
          .map((i) => PopupMenuItem(
                height: _itemHeight,
                child: Text('Item $i'),
                value: i,
              ))
          .toList(),
    ),
  );
}
```

---

**Edit:** Unfortunately even if you wrap the child of the `PopupMenuItem` with `SizedBox` and set a `width` to fill the screen width, it won't work because `PopupMenuItem` has a `maxWidth` (`_kMenuMaxWidth`).

Here is a way to make something similar using `AnimatedContainer`:

```
final _itemHeight = 80.0;
final _values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var _selectedValue = 1;
var _expanded = false;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Text('Item $_selectedValue'),
          ),
          onTap: () => setState(() => _expanded = !_expanded),
        ),
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
          height: _expanded ? _itemHeight * _values.length : 0,
          child: ListView(
            primary: false,
            children: _values
                .map(
                  (value) => SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    height: _itemHeight,
                    child: Material(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Text('Item $value'),
                        onTap: () => setState(
                          () {
                            _selectedValue = value;
                            _expanded = false;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How I can change width of popup?

Comment: You could wrap the child of the PopupMenuItem with a SizedBox and set a width.

Comment: I try this, but PopupMenuitem not showed by full screen width, I wrap it by sizedbox it's not help. There would be a way to call an animated widget using dropdownmenu or PopupMenuButton, we could make a separate page with a choice, and call it when you click a button.